# Updateable view dependent on mutiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

I am reading about `Updateable View` in [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/view-updatability.html):

> To be more specific, a view is not updatable if it contains any of the
>   following:   ....
>
> *Certain* joins (see additional join discussion later in this section)

And after that:

> It is sometimes possible for a multiple-table view to be updatable,
>   assuming that it can be processed with the MERGE algorithm. For this
>   to work, the view must use an inner join (not an outer join or a
>   UNION).

But there is no clear example and I was not succesful in updating a view I created that involved a `NATURAL JOIN`.

What would be an example of a view that depends on `multi-tables` that is updateable? And when not?

Answer (score 6):

Sample table schema

```
CREATE TABLE customers(customer_id INT, `name` VARCHAR(32));
CREATE TABLE orders(order_id INT, customer_id INT, order_date DATE);
```

The view

```
CREATE VIEW vw_orders AS 
SELECT order_id, o.customer_id order_customer_id, c.customer_id, c.name customer_name, order_date
  FROM orders o INNER JOIN 
       customers c ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id;
```

Then you can insert like this

```
INSERT INTO vw_orders (customer_id, customer_name) VALUES (1, 'Customer1');
INSERT INTO vw_orders (order_id, order_customer_id, order_date) VALUES (1, 1, CURDATE());
```

or UPDATE

```
UPDATE vw_orders SET customer_name = 'Customer11' WHERE customer_id = 1;
```

*Note: you won't be able to insert or update values in both underlying tables with a single statement*

This statement

```
INSERT INTO vw_orders (customer_id, customer_name, order_id, order_customer_id, order_date) 
VALUES (2, 'Customer2', 2, 2, CURDATE());
```

will fail with an error

```
Can not modify more than one base table through a join view 'vw_orders'
```